# Can no longer rename calendar events in Outlook since update

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, calendar

I used to be able to change the name of a meeting that another person organized in order to better identify the event. In a recent update of Outlook, I can no longer do that and I have to click on the event to see the details. This is really a major productivity killer. I'm on a Mac. My husband who uses a PC can still edit the titles of meetings organized by others. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What's the detailed version of Outlook for Mac?
I tested this issue on my side(version 16.24). Subject of calendar cannot be changed for attendees.

According to the reply of our MVP in [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/rename-calendar-meeting-created-by-another/94e34463-4ba0-46a7-b797-9461a7aa9232?page=2), this feature may be changed and only organizer can edit the calendar items.